# why this naming convention for padding as "Same" and "Valid" in keras

Tags: keras, cnn

I was going through CNN's and found that padding argument should be set to "Valid" if i need no padding and "Same" if i need padding. But, it doesn't make any sense to me. Why can't keras development team just put "Padding = True", is there a specific reason to choose this convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `valid` will essentially use as much of your input as possible, such that the dimensions continue to work. This means there is a chance some input will be *trimmed* (removed).

`same` on the other hand, will add padding to allow e.g. the number of filters/convolutions you specify to be applied.

The reason not to simply have *padding=True* as an option, is that there are more than two options (see snippet from the docs below). Also, that would not be very explicit: using `same` or `valid` makes it crystal clear, what the result should be using the given approach.

This is what the documentation says:

> - padding: One of "valid", "causal" or "same" (case-insensitive).  **"valid"** means "no padding".  **"same"** results in padding the input such that the output has the same length as the original input

Take a look at this nice [answer with a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213051/what-are-padding-valid-in-keras-conv2d-and-how-to-disable-padding).